# Инициализация массива объектов

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, матрицы, инициализация

### Инициализация массива объектов (C++)

Здравствуйте, уважаемое сообщество. Столкнулся с ситуацией, требующей Вашего пояснения.

Имеется примитивный класс **Vector**, в котором реализованы все нужные для проекта операции/методы (по условию проекта использовать **std::vector** запрещено).

Ниже представлена часть класса:

```
class Vector {
  private:
    double *mem;
    int count;
  public:
    Vector();
    explicit Vector(int count);
    Vector(int count, double filler);
    Vector(const Vector& vec);
    ~Vector();
  ................
}
```

Имеется класс **Matrix**, часть представлена ниже:

```
class Matrix {
  private:
    int rowsNum;
    int columnsNum;
    Vector *rows;
  public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int rowsNum, int columnsNum);
    Matrix(int rowsNum, int columnsNum, double filler);
    Matrix(const Matrix& matr);
    ~Matrix();
  ...............
}
```

Конструктор-инициализатор, принимающий два параметра, реализован следующим образом:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rowsNum, int columnsNum) 
{
  this->rowsNum = rowsNum;
  this->columnsNum = columnsNum;
  rows = new Vector[rowsNum];
  for (int i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
    rows[i] = Vector(columnsNum);
}
```

Собственно, интересует следующая строка кода:

```
rows[i] = Vector(columnsNum);
```

Дело в том, что все вышеописанное отрабатывает прекрасно без каких бы то ни было ошибок. Меня интересует вопрос, можно ли так вообще делать. Разумеется, можно написать метод класса **Vector**, работа которого была бы аналогичной тому, что делает конструктор этого класса. Но, опять же, если вышеприведенный код полностью "легален", то в этом нет никакой необходимости.

Хотелось бы услышать Ваши комментарии по этому поводу.

P.S. Операция присваивания векторов в классе **Vector** перегружена.

Comment: Это псевдо код? [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "Не вижу препятствий" (с)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, скажем так, я бы добавил перемещающее присваивание для пущей эффективности, только и всего. Ну, может, переписал бы так:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rowsNum, int columnsNum) 
:rowsNum(rowsNum),columnsNum(columnsNum),
rows(new Vector[rowsNum])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsNum; i++)
        rows[i] = Vector(columnsNum);
}
```